# Summing with foldLeft

Tags: scala

In this code I'm attempting to sum the xor values of two Strings :

```
val s1 = "1c0111001f010100061a024b53535009181c";
val s2 = "686974207468652062756c6c277320657965";
val zs : IndexedSeq[(Char, Char)] = s1.zip(s2);
zs.foldLeft(0)((a , b) => (a._1 ^ a._2) + (b._1 ^ b._2))
```

I receive error message :

```
value _1 is not a member of Int
[error]         zs.foldLeft(0)((a , b) => (a._1 ^ a._2) + (b._1 ^ b._2))
[error]                                      ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Oct 20, 2016 12:51:11 PM
```

As I'm folding over `(Char, Char)` should summing over xor of corresponding values be valid ?

Comment: The problem is the `(0)`. It then assumes you mean the first parameter to be an `Int`.

Comment: The `a` is the accumulated value of the previous folds. `b` is your current `(Char, Char)` tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `a` is not a `Tuple`. If you annotate the function you pass to `foldLeft` you should see the problem:

```
val s1 = "1c0111001f010100061a024b53535009181c";
val s2 = "686974207468652062756c6c277320657965";
val zs : IndexedSeq[(Char, Char)] = s1.zip(s2);
val sum = zs.foldLeft(0)((a: Int , b: (Char, Char)) => a + (b._1 ^ b._2))
```

Remember that `a` is the accumulator and `b` is the current value. You want to accumulate `Int`s so `a` has to be of the same type as the seed you specify (`0`).

Of course you could write the above without the explicit annotations:

```
zs.foldLeft(0)((a, b) => a + (b._1 ^ b._2))
```

An even easier way would be to map it to an Int beforehand and then use the `sum` function:

```
val sum = s1.zip(s2)
  .map(cs => cs._1 ^ cs._2)
  .sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
zs.foldLeft(0)((a , b) => a + (b._1 ^ b._2))
```

Try that